# Conflicting parseable interfaces for Swift Module FBSDKCoreKit

Tags: flutter, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm currently using facebook_ios_sdk but when I add facebook_app_events from pubdev to monitor events on facebook, I get the following error when distribute to testflight.

[image]

When I look at the error detail, I see the following error and I couldn't find how to solve it for days.

```
warning: Conflicting parseable interfaces for Swift Module FBSDKCoreKit: /Users/ugurcan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cwlltxgcsxqiyvfovdsmetlzlkzz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Modules/FBSDKCoreKit.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface and /Users/ugurcan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cwlltxgcsxqiyvfovdsmetlzlkzz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Modules/FBSDKCoreKit.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.private.swiftinterface
note: while processing /Users/ugurcan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-cwlltxgcsxqiyvfovdsmetlzlkzz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/facebook_app_events/facebook_app_events.framework/facebook_app_events(SwiftFacebookAppEventsPlugin.o)
```

I want to publish to testflight without conflicts.